# google app engine yaml-3.10 error

Tags: google-app-engine

Lately I've been getting this strange error in most of the requests to my Google App Engine app. This causes a new process to be started with every request and is making the whole app incredibly slow. Any ideeas about what I might be doing wrong?

> ['lib', '/base/data/home/apps/s~some_app_name/1.23',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/markupsafe-0.15',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/setuptools-0.6c11',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/ssl-2.7',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
>   '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']

Comment: It doesn't look like an error.  It look more like you have left a print somewhere.  Where is the rest of the error message from the logs ?

Comment: Oh, indeed someone forgot a print sys.path in the code. Thanks for the quick answer! Still don't understand why that was making a new process to be started for every request.

Comment: THats a seperate issue.  Put some logging in place, and record whats going in.  and show your app.yaml and main handler, that might give us some information to allow us to help.