# Upgrade App Engine Python ssl to 2.7.11 by Mar 1, 2018

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I have received an notification in email from GAE team about the need to upgrade to SSL 2.7.11. It is because my projects are still using 2.7

However in my yaml file, the ssl is set to `latest`

```
 - name: ssl
  version: latest
```

My questions are

1) Do I need to change the version explicitly to '2.7.11'? If I stay with `latest` will the library be automatically rolled over to 2.7.11

2) Is it possible to identify in cloud console to check the ssl version? I want to confirm the change of version has taken place after the yaml file is updated

3) Is there a minimum set of tests that should be performed to verify there is no  breakage in term of functionality?

Comment: IMHO it's preferable to use an explicit version rather than relying on defaults, if possible - it offers a chance to somehow control the migration: tests can be executed to catch problems and fixes can be developed without pressure, better than putting out fires after the deadline is reached (or when defaults are changed, whatever the reason).

Comment: When was the last time you deployed your app?  I suspect that apps get updated to the latest version when they are deployed.  If you haven't deployed in awhile, you might be out of date.

Comment: For some things, all you have to do is redeploy your app. This might be one of those times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, IMHO it's preferable to use an explicit version rather than relying on defaults, if possible - it offers a chance to somehow control the migration: tests can be executed to catch problems and fixes can be developed without pressure, better than putting out fires after the deadline is reached (or when defaults are changed, for whatever reason). Also practically eliminates #2 :)

For #2 - I don't know of a place in the developer console, but you could temporarily (just to get the answer) either:

- add an app log message displaying `sys.path` in a related portion of your app code. The output typically includes paths to each of the runtime-provided libraries used in your app, most (if not all) of which include the version number in snippets like `third_party/ssl-2.7`. See, for example, [google app engine yaml-3.10 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705765/google-app-engine-yaml-3-10-error).
- force a crash in the `ssl` library (by passing some invalid arguments, for example) - the stack trace also includes the above-mentioned snippets.

For #3 I don't know of some official or recommended tests, I can only suggest testing that your app keeps working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For testing update add a (temporary endpoint to check that ssl module has HAS_ALPN property, or another functionality which was added after 2.7 ( cannot find anything exactly specific for 2.7.11, but there are few 2.7.10 specific.)